Jest testing keeps running forever
I have created a small jest test, and it seems like running forever:
export default class Core {
    app: any;
    port: string | undefined;

    constructor() {
        this.port = process.env.server_port;
        this.app = express();
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    }

    dispatch() {
        this.app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            return routes(req, res, next);
        })

        const server = this.app.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log('server is running')
        })

        server.close();
    }

    returnInstance() {
        return this.app;
    }
}

const core = new Core();
core.dispatch();


const app = core.returnInstance();

const payloadCorrectLoginCredentials = {
    email: 'justforfun@fun.co',
    password: '1234'
};



    describe('Customer api', () => {
        test('[POST] /login, with correct credentials', async () => {
            const response = await request(app)
                .post('/api/customer/login')
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
                .send(payloadCorrectLoginCredentials)
    
            expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    
        });
    });

I have tried to actually closing the server when the jest call is done, then again, how to mark it done() in async?
